# Connect to a VPN server through a Raspberry (connected VPN client)

Tags: network, wifi, ssh, vpn

I'm trying to connect from my MacBook to the VPN server, which is accessible from the Raspberry as it's a connected VPN client.

```
MacBook (172.25.0.139) ---> Raspberry (172.25.0.14) ---> [INTERNET] ---> VPN Server (172.26.0.x)
```

Raspberry is already connected to that VPN server, so I can reach it and connect to it via ssh **FROM** the raspberry.

As I'm connected to the same LAN than the raspberry, I'd guessed that it should be as simple as adding a route on my Mac to tell my MacBook that it should reach the
VPN Server through the raspberry.

✅ Raspberry connected to VPN server (172.26.0.99).

✅ Raspberry is able to connect to the VPN server via ssh using the VPN LAN address (172.26.0.99)

✅ MacBook (172.25.0.139) can connect to Raspberry (172.25.0.14).

❌ MacBook (172.25.0.139) CANNOT connect to VPN server (172.26.0.99) THROUGH Raspberry (172.25.0.14).

### MacBook

I set the route using networksetup

```
networksetup -setadditionalroutes "Wi-Fi" 172.26.0.99 255.255.255.255 172.25.0.14
```

I think I did it properly as I can see the `tcpdump`:

```
tcpdump -n |grep 172.26.0.99
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
11:02:51.053672 IP 172.25.0.139.53549 > 172.26.0.99.22: Flags [S], seq 2856180432, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 718632786 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
11:02:52.058006 IP 172.25.0.139.53549 > 172.26.0.99.22: Flags [S], seq 2856180432, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 718633786 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
11:02:53.059068 IP 172.25.0.139.53549 > 172.26.0.99.22: Flags [S], seq 2856180432, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 718634786 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
^C63 packets captured
84 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

### Raspberry

```
 ✘ raspberrypi ✝ ~  netstat -nr -f inet
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         172.25.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
169.254.1.0     169.254.1.13    255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 tun0
169.254.1.13    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
172.25.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
172.26.0.0      169.254.1.13    255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 tun0

 ✘ raspberrypi ✝ ~  ssh 172.26.0.99
Linux OpenVPN Host server 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27) x86_64
Last login: Tue Jul 16 11:50:01 2019 from 169.254.1.14
 user ✝ ~ ✅
```

Comment: By connect, are you usin ssh to hop from machine to machine or does connect mean you are setting up the Unix on raspberry pi hardware to function as network hardware opening a point to point vpn tunnel to another network segment?

Comment: Raspberry is connected to the VPN server via OpenVPN and can ssh to openvpn server SSH server.

Comment: Raspberry would not redirect incoming packets to the vpn connection without configuration. Keywords: Linux, iptables, redirect traffic, masquerade

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer below instead of including it in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @andrew-morozko suggested, Raspberry does not not redirect incoming packets to the vpn connection without configuration:

```
  sudo iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
  sudo iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i tun0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
  sudo iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i eth0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```